# Tensorflow print in function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a function in a file `neural_network.py` that defines a loss function:

```
def loss(a, b):
    ...
    debug = tf.Print(a, [a], message = 'debug: ')
    debug.eval(session = ???)
    return tf.add(a, b)
```

To explain, somewhere in this function I want to print a tensor. However, I don't have any session declared in this function; my sessions are declared in another file called `forecaster.py`. Therefore, when I try to put `tf.Print()` in `loss()`, I can't because I don't know which session to `eval` with. Is there a way to solve this problem, either by using `tf.Print()` or other debug methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`tf.Print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/debugging_operations#Print) works as an identity function which returns the same tensor that you passed as the first parameter, having a side effect of printing the list of tensors specified as the second parameter.

So you should use as following:

```
def loss(a, b):
    ...
    a = tf.Print(a, [a], message = 'debug: ')
    return tf.add(a, b)
```

`a` will be printed each time tensor `tf.add(a, b)` is evaluated.